# how to reload appended data in an Iframe

Tags: php, html, css

after appending some data in an iframe using JQuery i need to reload the appended data. the data contains some script tags.

this is an example of the code i appended to an iframe. the div will apear into the iframe but the script won't work. the alert i added appears but for some reason the JQuery code won't transform the div into a dialog.
I said maybe it's because i should reload the appended data in this iframe. is it possible?

```
<style>
   .draggable { width: 90px; height: 80px; padding: 5px; float: left; margin: 0 10px 10px 0; font-size: .9em; }
   .ui-widget-header p, .ui-widget-content p { margin: 0; }
   #snaptarget { height: 140px; }
</style>

<script type="text/javascript">
   $(function() {
     window.alert("TEST dialog1");
     $( "#dialog1" ).dialog({ title: "Notifications Widget" });
     $( "#dialog1" ).dialog( "option", "position", [200,200] );
     $( "#dialog1" ).dialog().parents(".ui-dialog").draggable("option", "snap", true);
   });
</script>

<div id="dialog1" class="draggable ui-widget-content">
   <p>I am a notification widget</p>
</div>
```

thanks for helping

Comment: show code which appends that HTML to an iframe

Comment: var iframeBody  = $("#droppable").contents ().find("body");
iframeBody.append(data);

Comment: Do you have a jQuery linked inside iFrame?

Comment: the script shown in the example is a JQuery

Answer (score 0):

> the alert i added appears but for some reason the JQuery code won't
>   transform the div into a dialog.

Alert appears, so your script is actually added and works fine. Remember that you must have jQuery, jQuery UI, css or what ever else required for your code to work correctly being  linked inside iFrame just like . It has no direct access to parent window code. You may think about it like another browser tab/window.

Comment: the Jquery ui is linked correctly. the iframe loads by default a page that contains many dialogs that work fine, but the problem is when i append new data to it.

Comment: Oh. Wait. Try to remove that `$(function(){...})` around your code. Not sure why alert is show at all (possibly, it is outside ready function in your actual code). But ready callback is called after page is loaded and only once.

Comment: if there's a way to reload the current data to the iframe i think it may resolve the problem.

Comment: `i tried it and it didn't work` but did you place your js code AFTER #dialog1 div? It must be there, otherwise $("#dialog1") will find nothing as it will be executed before div is added to a DOM

Comment: that's right, and i've already put it before the #dialog1 div as shown in the example

Comment: But why if it must be AFTER #dialog1 div?

Comment: what might help is to find a way to reload the iframe with its existing content and not using its original src

Comment: What do you get in result? Here: http://jsfiddle.net/en5RY/2/ I see that it works just fine.

Comment: it will work when the page loads but not when you append some data using ajax JQuery functions after the page finish loading

Comment: Why do you think so? For instance, here code will be appended after you click on a button: http://jsfiddle.net/en5RY/3/. And it works fine. See no difference between code added in event of ajax or button. So again. What do you get in result instead of popup?

Comment: the function works when the page is loading. when my page is loading, the original contents work fine, but when i press on the button, it will get the code from another page and append it to the iframe. the "notification widget" appears in this iframe but with no dialog functionality and it cannot be even dragged.

Comment: well, I'm afraid I can't help you with that without seeing what exactly happens. As a possible solutions - do not append a dialog after ajax call, just make it visible (possibly, simply update your some text inside dialog body if it may be different)